# Is $f′′(x) \ge 0$, then $g′′(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis

Is this true?

If $\{f_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ and $g$ are twice differentiable functions such that, for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}f_j(x) = g(x)$ and $f′′(x) \ge 0$, then $g′′(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Would taylor series work here? Any hint out there?

Comment: Diddy.A question from out there .By $f'' \ge 0$ you mean $f_j'' \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The condition that $f'' \geq 0$ is equivalent to convexity of $f$. From definition of convexity you can easily verify that pointwise limits of convex functions are convex.